# Google App Engine: Failing to Upload Data

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to upload data in a Googl App Engine application as explained in this post https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata

I am therefore executing this command (from Eclipse PyDev)

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=album_loader.py --filename=album_data.csv --kind=Album http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```

But I get the following error:

```
Usage: appcfg.py [options] upload_data <directory>

appcfg.py: error: Not a directory: http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api 
FINISHED
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a `--url` missing from the example:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=album_loader.py --filename=album_data.csv --kind=Album --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api
```